# Como mostrar los primeros 100 números primos en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, números-primos

Estoy intentando mostrar los primeros 100 números primos. Realicé este código pero, no se porque no me funciona. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme por favor!!

```
        int num=1;
        int i;
        int cont=0;

        while (num<=100)
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                {
                    cont = cont + 1;
                }
            }
            if (cont == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Es primo");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No es primo");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Creo que el problema es que inicializas la variable `cont` una única vez, al principio del programa. Debes iniciarla antes del bucle for, para que la cuenta de los únicos divisores (la unidad y el mismo) se inicialice en cada número. Sino quedan incrementados siempre, de manera que solo te funciona para el número 1 ( en tu caso al comprobar el 2 tienes cont a 3, debido a la división de 2%1, 2%2 y el de 1%1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para encontrar un número primo tienes que dividir el número entre todos los números anterios a el para comprobar si es divisible por alguno, si lo es, no es primo.

Para comprobar un solo número el código sería:

```
       //número a evaluar
        int n = 11;
        //variable auxiliar para guardar el resultado de la evaluacion
        boolean esPrimo = true;

        //se divide el numero n entre todos los numeros anteriores
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            //si el modulo de la division es 0 entonces el numero no es primo
            //se marca la variable esPrimo como false y se termina el for
            if( n % i == 0){
                esPrimo = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // si la variable esPrimo es true entonces es un numero primo
        if(esPrimo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Es primo");
        }
```

Pero como se necesita los primeros 100 entonces se mete el código anterior dentro de un while y se crea un contador para llevar el registro de los números primos encontrados:

```
        //variable que contiene el numero que se está probando
        int n = 2;
        //variable que contiene el total de numeros primos encontrados
        int total = 1;

        //iterar mientras el total de numeros primos no se mayor a 100
        while(total <= 100){

            //variable que indica si un numero es primo o no
            boolean esPrimo = true;

            //se divide el numero (n) entre todos los numeros anterios a el
            //si el modulo de la division es 0 significa que el numero no es primo
            //y se marca la variable esPrimo = false y se termina el ciclo for
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                if(n % i == 0)
                {
                    esPrimo = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

            //si despues de ejecutar el ciclo for la variable esPrimo sigue
            //teniendo un valor true entonces se imprime el numero y se incrementa
            // el contador de numeros encontrados total++
            if(esPrimo)
            {
             Console.WriteLine(n);
              total++;
            }
            //se incrementa para evaluar el siguiente número
            n++;
        }
```

Comment: Master, de verdad eres un genio, pero ahora tengo la siguiente duda, en el código se imprime el numero 1, pero el 1 no es un numero primo!!

Comment: Un número primo es aquel que solo es divisible entre el mismo y la unidad y MAYOR QUE 1, por lo cual el numero 1 no seria primo.

Comment: De acuerdo, me había confundido. Puedes cambiar la variable `n` para que empiece en 2. `n = 2`